# Расчёт корней квадратного уравнения с помощью языка PHP

Tags: php

Как нужно реализовать на PHP расчёт корней квадратного уравнения с отображением результатов расчёта?

Comment: @Игорь Бурименко, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Что делали, что не получилось?!

Comment: в данном случае ответ на вопрос будет звучать както так:
* грамотно
* правильно
* красиво

ответ можете выбрать сами :)

Comment: Формула корней квадратного уравнения:
D = b^2-4ac. x1,2 = (-b-(+)sqrt(D))/2a. Если D<0 => корней нет. Если D>0 => 2 корня. Если D = 0 => 1 корень. 
Вам осталось это только выразить в PHP

Comment: При D<0 нет вещественных корней, но есть комплексные.

Comment: не думаю, что человеку это надо..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
if (isset($_GET['send'])){
    $a = (int) $_GET['a'];
    $b = (int) $_GET['b'];
    $c = (int) $_GET['c'];

    $result = eq_roots($a, $b, $c);
}
function eq_roots($a, $b, $c) {
    if ($a==0) return false;

    if ($b==0) {
        if ($c<0) {
            $x1 = sqrt(abs($c/$a));
            $x2 = sqrt(abs($c/$a));
        } elseif ($c==0) {
            $x1 = $x2 = 0;
        } else {
            $x1 = sqrt($c/$a).'i';
            $x2 = -sqrt($c/$a).'i';
        }
    } else {
        $d = $b*$b-4*$a*$c;
        if ($d>0) {
            $x1 = (-$b+sqrt($d))/2*$a;
            $x2 = (-$b-sqrt($d))/2*$a;
        } elseif ($d==0) {
            $x1 = $x2 = (-$b)/2*$a;
        } else {
            $x1 = -$b . '+' . sqrt(abs($d)) . 'i';
            $x2 = -$b . '-' . sqrt(abs($d)) . 'i';
        }
    }
    return array($x1, $x2);
}
?>

<p>Введите коэффициенты :</p>
<h4>a * x<sup>2</sup> + b * x + с = 0</h4>
<form method="GET">
    <p>a = <input type="text" name="a" /></p>
    <p>b = <input type="text" name="b" /></p>
    <p>c = <input type="text" name="c" /></p>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="решить"/>
</form>

<? if (isset($result)): ?>
<hr />
<h3><?=$a ?> * x<sup>2</sup> + <?=$b ?> * x + <?=$c ?> = 0</h3>
<p>Корни уравнения :</p>
<p>X<sub>1</sub> = <?=$result[0] ?></p>
<p>X<sub>2</sub> = <?=$result[1] ?></p>
<? endif ?>
```

так будет)

Answer (score 0):

```
function quadratic_equation($num1, $num2, $num3) {
 if (!empty($num1) and !empty($num2) and !empty($num3)) {
        $dis = (pow($num2, 2)) - (4 * ($num1 * $num3));
        if ($dis > 0) {
            $x1 = -($num2 + sqrt($dis)/(2 * $num1));
            $x2 = -($num2 - sqrt($dis)/(2 * $num1));
            echo "Первый корень уровнения x1 = $x1 <br>Второй корень уровнения x2 = $x2";
        } elseif ($dis == 0) {
            $x1 = $x2 = -($num2/(2 * $num1));
            echo "Оба корня равны и имеют значение $x1";
        } elseif ($dis < 0) {
            echo 'Действительных корней нет.';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Примерно так нужно считать, а как вы будете это выводить - решайте сами.

```
function eq_roots($a, $b, $c) {
    if ($a==0) return false;

    if ($b==0) {
        if ($c<0) {
            $x1 = sqrt(abs($c/$a));
            $x2 = sqrt(abs($c/$a));
        } elseif ($c==0) {
            $x1 = $x2 = 0;
        } else {
            $x1 = sqrt($c/$a).'i';
            $x2 = -sqrt($c/$a).'i';
        }
    } else {
        $d = $b*$b-4*$a*$c;
        if ($d>0) {
            $x1 = (-$b+sqrt($d))/2/$a;
            $x2 = (-$b-sqrt($d))/2/$a;
        } elseif ($d==0) {
            $x1 = $x2 = (-$b)/2/$a;
        } else {
            $x1 = -$b . '+' . sqrt(abs($d)) . 'i';
            $x2 = -$b . '-' . sqrt(abs($d)) . 'i';
        }
    }
    return array($x1, $x2);
}
```

Comment: в случае с d == 0 словим варнинг о необъявленной переменной

Comment: Ткните пальцем, о какой переменной идет речь?